# Change avatar background color in Skype Web

Tags: skype-for-web

How do I change the avatar background color in Skype Web?

[image: Skype avatar background color]

I've followed [these instructions](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34792/how-do-i-change-my-profile-color-in-skype) but it didn't work for the avatar color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in section 4 of [these instructions](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34792/how-do-i-change-my-profile-color-in-skype), it took 'a little time' (in my case, 4 days) to the background color to change.